# Vk mini app на react. Как на стороне php сформировать json ответ?

Tags: php, json, reactjs, vk-mini-apps

Решил разобраться с созданием приложений на VK MiniApps и застрял на очевидном.
Требуется сделав запрос на php скрипт с приложения. Получить из него данные в json для дальнейшей работы с ними.
Имеем для теста php скрипт:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS');
$json = array(
                'site_url' => array(
                    'URL' => 1234,
                    ),
                    );
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($json);
?
```

> 

Он выдает нам json ответ: `{"site_url":{"URL":1234}}`
На стороне приложения использую вот такую часть кода:

```
axios
      .get("https://site.pw/app/zx.php")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

При обращении к нему выдает ошибку Error:

```
Network Error
at createError (https://oe8vd.csb.app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (https://oe8vd.csb.app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:91:14)
```

При этом делая обращении по ссылке (https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_EUR&compact=y&apiKey=88bb8bbba9a29716dfd5)
Которая выдает такой же json, все считывается. Ошибка видимо в формировании самого json на php.
Вот проект на codesendbox https://codesandbox.io/s/alexastr-oe8vd?file=/src/App.js:673-864

Comment: ошибка точно не на стороне php. Проблема в ssl сертификате, скорее всего по адрессу https://site.pw его попросту нет. Гуглите в сторону axios/http

Comment: Сайт имеет сертификат. Вот ссылка на страницу скрипта https://antiscam.pw/app/zx.php с этим не должно быть проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Причина нашлась. Но как ее решить так и не понял. Проблема оказалась из за cloudflare. Они меняют header или держат в кэше. Кеш там чистил, но не помогло. Так же пробовал Development mode. Но так же не помогло. На сервере без проксирования cloudflare все работает. В какую сторону  копать дальше не знаю.